# FTP Deployment in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ftp, eclipse-plugin

Aside from DeployerFTP, are there any plugins that offer the ability to deploy a project to an FTP location? I would love a way to do this on an individual file basis, possibly even storing the FTP information within each project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANT: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html

Maven: http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-ftp/

Answer (score 2):

The [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) suite of Eclipse tools has FTP built right in. You have to purchase the full version to be able to sync via other methods like SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Eclipse Remote System Explorer tools. There is some screen casts on the project web site http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/

EDIT:

The web site is now http://www.eclipse.org/tm/

Answer (score 1):

As none of the other solutions I found satisfied me, I wrote my own script that uses WinSCP to sync local folders in a project folder to remote folders. Maybe this is what you're looking for, although this only works on Windows:
http://rays-blog.de/2012/05/05/94/use-winscp-to-upload-files-using-eclipses-autobuild-feature/